# Add features to non-public feature layer using REST API

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-rest-api

I have a feature layer that I query from a python script using the ARCGIS REST API. I also call the Geoprocessing service to create buffers, etc. all using a token generated via my [portal_root]/oauth2/token endpoint. The APP ID and Secret that I use were generated in the same portal. All queries work fine, even if the services are not published publicly.

```
data = {
  'client_id':os.environ['CLIENT_ID'],
  'client_secret':os.environ['CLIENT_SECRET'],
  'grant_type':'client_credentials'
}

response = requests.post('{}/{}'.format(os.environ['PORTAL_ROOT'],'oauth2/token'), data=data, verify=True)

if response.ok== False:
  raise Exception("Could not authenticate to arcgis")
else:
  content = json.loads(response.content)
  token = content["access_token"]
  print('][==Authenticated==][')
```

I can then do things like:

```
apiEndpoint='Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer/buffer'

data = {
  'geometries':json.dumps(quoteLocationGeometry),
  'inSR':4326,
  'outSR':102100,
  'distances':2000,
  'unit':9001,
  'token':token,
  'f':'json'
}

response = requests.post('{}/{}'.format(os.environ['SERVER_ROOT'],apiEndpoint), data=data, verify=True)
# Sprint(response.text)
if response.ok== False:
  raise Exception("Could not get Buffer",response.text)
else:
  quoteLocationBuffer = json.loads(response.content)
```

This all works fine. The last step in my script is to write some data back to a feature service/layer:

```
apiEndpoint = 'Hosted/SavedQuotes/FeatureServer/0/addFeatures'

feat = solvedRoutes['routes']['features'][0]
data = {
   'token':token,
   'f':'json',
   'features':json.dumps([{
     'attributes':{
      'details':feat['attributes']['Name'],
      'total_cost':feat['attributes']['Total_Cost'],
      'total_length':feat['attributes']['Total_Length'],
      'SHAPE__Length' : feat['attributes']['Shape_Length'],
      'origin_latitude' : lat,
      'origin_longitude' : lon,
      'rid':args.rid,
      'creator_userid' : 'some user ID or email',
      'creator_email' : 'user@email.com',
      'creation_date': int(time.time())*1000
   },
    'geometry':{
      'spatialReference':solvedRoutes['routes']['spatialReference'],
      'paths':feat['geometry']['paths']
    }
    }])
   }

print(json.dumps(data))
response = requests.post('{}/{}'.format(os.environ['SERVER_ROOT'],apiEndpoint), data=data, verify=True)

if response.ok== False:
  raise Exception("Could not Save Quote",response.text)

print(response.content)
```

This call fails with a:

```
'{"error":{"code":500,"message":"User does not have the privilege to perform this operation.","details":[]}}
```

If I make the Feature layer public, the write works fine, so I know the API call is formatted correctly. I have a valid Auth token, and all READ operations work fine using this token. I opened a ticket with ESRI and it was closed with "sorry, you can't write to a feature layer using OAuth. The layer has to be public. I 100% cannot believe this to be the case. Why can't I write to a feature layer using the REST API + OAuth? The ESRI rep kept sending me docs on the Portal Administration REST api, even after me sending the script and describing in detail what I am trying to do, he just keeps saying it's not possible. He did say I could call the generateToken endpoint with a username and password, but the docs state that interface is superseded by OAuth, and we use OAuth everywhere. It's not adding up.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't get full owner privileges to your account resources unless you go through the full OAuth process. For example:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import requests
import webbrowser

portal_root = 'https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest'

params = {
    'client_id': 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    'response_type': 'code',
    'redirect_uri': 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',
    'expiration': 1440
}

auth_url = portal_root + '/oauth2/authorize?' + urlencode(params)
webbrowser.open(auth_url)
auth_code = input('Enter Approval Code: ')

data = {
    'client_id': 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'code': auth_code,
    'redirect_uri': 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',
    'f': 'json'
}

auth_response = requests.post(portal_root + '/oauth2/token', data)
token_data = auth_response.json()
```